# 'I am being loved by my mom.' is possible?

Tags: grammar, syntax

I want to know if it is possible to make a sentence like 'I am being loved by my mom.'

If it is possible, What is the meaning you get when you see this sentence?
Please, tell me.

Comment: It's possible because you just made one.  This is kind of a strange question, asking people to make up a sentence and then to describe what it means to them.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Are you trying to say, "My mom loves me."?

Comment: What are you trying to express with this sentence that isn't the same as "I am loved by my mom"?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but awkward.  When "love" is used in the present progressive tense it usually means sexual love, passive voice or no.  Pick a different verb it's fine, "I'm being served dinner by my mom".

Answer (score 1):

If you're speaking in general terms of the fact that your mom loves you, you would say "My mom loves me."

Your original sentence makes sense grammatically, but "being loved" when used in the present-tense is often related to romantic (or sexual) love. So the original sentence may come off as strange to some readers.

Comment: You mean 'when used in present -progressive-tense'?

Comment: You're likely correct. I'm not well studied on formal English terminology despite being a native speaker.